# How to display "About the author" tab in article display page?

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to basically override the normal display of article, to include two tabs in that. One tab will be "Read Article", which when clicks loads the article page. Others tab will be "About the Author", which when clicks loads the author page.

So ultimately when I go to any article page, there will be two tabs, "Read Aricle" (selected by default), and "About the author".

Please suggest how can I achieve this. I have tried overriding node display by using [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), but I am not able to add links or display author information in another tab.

-- Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Author Pane](http://drupal.org/project/author_pane)

> Author Pane is a block of information about a given user, like those
>   typically found on a forum post, but can be used in other places as
>   well. From core, it collects the user picture, name, join date, online
>   status, contact link, and profile information. In addition, any module
>   or theme can feed it more information via the preprocess system. All
>   of this information is then gathered and displayed using a template
>   file.

For the tabbed view you cold try [Quick Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs)

> The Quick Tabs module allows you to create blocks of tabbed content,
>   specifically views, blocks, nodes* and other quicktabs*.

Comment: It just display normal block with some data. Actually I have override display of author page too, and I want to load that page and not custom block. -- Thanks